# PostGIS Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

I am trying to use Npgsql and Npgsql.EntityFramework with a geography data type. I can write data to the database, but I'm unable to retrieve it. I am not sure if this is even possible, so I would appreciate any help.

The class that represents the table looks like this:

```
internal class Geo
{
    [Key, Column("geo_test_id")]
    public int GeoId { get; set; }

    [Column("geography")]
    public byte[] Geography { get; set; }
}
```

Data insertion is done like this:

```
var geog1 = System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText("POINT(-118.4079 33.9434)");
var geog2 = System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText("POINT(2.5559 49.0083)");

using (var db = new Database.MyDbContext())
{
    db.Geos.Add(new Database.Geo() { Geography = geog1.AsBinary() });
    db.Geos.Add(new Database.Geo() { Geography = geog2.AsBinary() });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Data retrieval is done like this:

```
using (var db = new Database.MyDbContext())
{
     var geos = from g in db.Geos
                     select g.Geography;
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error: `Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'.`

I also tried saving the geography data as a string. In this case I am able to retrieve it, but I can't create a DbGeography object from text.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

The changes I made to `ExpectedTypeConverter` class:

```
else if (expectedType == typeof(byte[]))
{
     if (currentType == typeof(Guid))
     {
         return ((Guid)value).ToByteArray();
     }
     else if (value is Array)
     {
         Array valueArray = (Array)value;
         int byteLength = Buffer.ByteLength(valueArray);
         byte[] bytes = new byte[byteLength];
         Buffer.BlockCopy(valueArray, 0, bytes, 0, byteLength);
         return bytes;
     }
     else if (currentType == typeof(System.String)) // this part was added
     {
         string hex = value.ToString();

         int numChars = hex.Length / 2;
         byte[] bytes = new byte[numChars];

         using (var sr = new StringReader(hex))
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++)
             {
                 bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
             }
         }

         return bytes;
     }
     else
     {
         // expect InvalidCastException from this call
         return Convert.ChangeType(value, expectedType);
     }
```

Comment: Hi, Marac!

We have a pull request which adds Postgis datatype support. Would it be possible for you to give it a try and let us know if it works ok for you?

Check it out at: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/pull/255

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Hi, thank you for your feedback. I downloaded the new version of Npgsql and I can see the `IGeometry` interface which was previously unavailable, but I don't understand how to use it :). Could you explain what should I do with above code to make use of newly implemented types? Thanks!

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Hi Francisco, I managed to get this thing to work, but not by utilizing the newly implemented `IGeometry` interface. In the `ExpectedTypeConverter` class in `if (expectedType == typeof(byte[]))` part of the code I added conversion to byte array if currentType is of type System.String. I'm not sure if this approach has any potential failure scenarios, so I would appreciate your input on this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Marac! Sorry for late response. Would you mind to post your changes? This would help me find the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ExpectedTypeConverter is an converter created by Josh to handle entity framework type conversions. I'm not very familiar with that code. When you post your changes I'll ask Josh to have a look at them.

Comment: What is the database type of the geography column in the database? It is text? If so, did you try to change it to bytea?

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Hi Francisco, thank you for getting back to me. I edited my question and added the changes I made to the ExpectedTypeConverter class. With these changes I'm able to save and retrieve data, but this does not allow me to make LINQ queries on geometry types I store in database. I use PostGis types `geometry` and `geography`. I guess Entity Framework support for the kind functionality I'm trying to achieve is not yet available. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks again for trying to help me :)

Comment: Where does your ExpectedTypeConverter fit into the framework?