# Postgis geography type using Npgsql for EntityFramework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

I have a table using the Postgis geography type:

```
CREATE TABLE Place (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    location GEOGRAPHY NOT NULL
);
```

How do I declare the location field in my entity class?

```
class Place {
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ??? location { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549088/postgis-entity-framework) but it was in 2014 and Npsql seems to have evolved to play with Postgis and to support .Net System.Data.Spatial. See the following Npsql issues that are now closed:

- [Npgsql 3.0.3 and postgis geometry types](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/807)
- [PostGIS support](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/529)
- [Postgis 2D support](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/pull/665)
- [Look into System.Data.Spatial for PostGIS](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/774)
- [System.Data.Spatial implementation](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/pull/793)

I couldn't find a clue in Npsql documentation about how using such features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Npgsql does include PostGIS support, it's partial - not all types are handled, and unfortunately `GEOGRAPHY` is on of them.

Here's the relevant issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1322, please go post a vote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed my GEOGRAPHY column to be a standard Postgres POINT with no more success. Can you tell if standard Postgres POINT is supposed to be supported ?

Comment: There are two point types: the built-in PostgreSQL POINT, and PostGIS's POINT - both are supported. If all you want is a point (x,y), the easiest is to go with the built-in point, which can be mapped by having a property of type NpgsqlPoint on your entity.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried and I got the "The field field1 has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID XXXXX)" error. Will try again, thank you.